# How to expose a Delphi set type via Soap

Tags: delphi, soap, set

I'm currently creating soap wrappers for some Delphi functions so that we can easily use them from PHP, C# and Delphi.

I wonder what's the best way to expose sets.

```
type
  TCountry     = (countryUnknown,countryNL,countryD,countryB,countryS,countryFIN,countryF,countryE,countryP,countryPl,countryL);
  TCountrySet  = set of TCountry;

function GetValidCountrySet(const LicensePlate:string; const PossibleCountriesSet:TCountrySet):TCountrySet;
```

I'm currently wrapping it like this for the soap server:

```
type 
  TCountryArray = array of TCountry;

function TVehicleInfo.GetValidCountrySet(const LicensePlate:string; const PossibleCountriesSet:TCountryArray):TCountryArray;
```

It works, but I need to write a lot of useless and ugly code to convert sets-->arrays and arrays-->sets.

Is there an easier, more elegant, or more generic way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use TypInfo and use a bit of clever casting.

```
uses TypInfo;

type
  TCountry = (cnyNone, cnyNL, cnyD, cnyGB, cnyF, cnyI);
  TCountrySet = set of TCountry;

  TCountryArray = array of TCountry;
  TEnumIntegerArray = array of Integer;
  TEnumByteArray = array of Byte;

function GetEnumNamesInSet(const aTypeInfo: PTypeInfo; const aValue: Integer; const aSeparator: string = ','): string;
var
  IntSet: TIntegerSet;
  i: Integer;
begin
  Result := '';
  Integer( IntSet ) := aValue;
  for i := 0 to SizeOf(Integer) * 8 - 1 do begin
    if i in IntSet then begin
      if Result <> '' then begin
        Result := Result + ',';
      end;
      Result := Result + GetEnumName(aTypeInfo, i);
    end;
  end;
end;

function SetToIntegerArray(const aTypeInfo: PTypeInfo; const aValue: Integer): TEnumIntegerArray;
var
  IntSet: TIntegerSet;
  i: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(Result, 0);
  Integer( IntSet ) := aValue;
  for i := 0 to SizeOf(Integer) * 8 - 1 do begin
    if i in IntSet then begin
      SetLength(Result, Length(Result) + 1);
      Result[Length(Result) - 1] := i;
    end;
  end;
end;

function SetToByteArray(const aTypeInfo: PTypeInfo; const aValue: Byte): TEnumByteArray;
var
  IntSet: TIntegerSet;
  i: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(Result, 0);
  Integer( IntSet ) := aValue;
  for i := 0 to SizeOf(Byte) * 8 - 1 do begin
    if i in IntSet then begin
      SetLength(Result, Length(Result) + 1);
      Result[Length(Result) - 1] := i;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Then use as:

```
procedure TEnumForm.FillMemo;
var
  Countries: TCountrySet;
//  EIA: TEnumIntegerArray;
  EBA: TEnumByteArray;
  CA: TCountryArray;
  i: Integer;
  cny: TCountry;
begin
  Countries := [cnyNL, cnyD];
  CountriesMemo.Text := GetEnumNamesInSet(TypeInfo(TCountry), Byte(Countries));
//  if SizeOf(TCountry) > SizeOf(Byte) then begin
//    EIA := SetToIntegerArray(TypeInfo(TCountry), Integer(Countries));
//  end else begin
    EBA := SetToByteArray(TypeInfo(TCountry), Byte(Countries));
//  end;
  CountriesMemo.Lines.Add('====');
  CountriesMemo.Lines.Add('Values in Array: ');
//  if SizeOf(TCountry) > SizeOf(Byte) then begin
//    CA := TCountryArray(EIA);
//  end else begin
    CA := TCountryArray(EBA);
//  end;
  for i := 0 to Length(CA) - 1 do begin
    CountriesMemo.Lines.Add(IntToStr(Ord(CA[i])));
  end;
  CountriesMemo.Lines.Add('====');
  CountriesMemo.Lines.Add('Names in Array: ');
//  if SizeOf(TCountry) > SizeOf(Byte) then begin
//    CA := TCountryArray(EIA);
//  end else begin
    CA := TCountryArray(EBA);
//  end;
  for i := 0 to Length(CA) - 1 do begin
    cny := CA[i];
    CountriesMemo.Lines.Add(GetEnumName(TypeInfo(TCountry), Ord(cny)));
  end;
end;
```

You will need to select the proper casting based on the size of the TCountry enum. If it has 8 members it will be a Byte, any bigger and it will be an Integer. Anyway, Delphi will complain on the cast of Byte(Countries) or Integer(Countries) when you get it wrong.

Please note:
The functions now take the TypeInfo of TCountry - the elements of the TCountrySet. They could be changed to take TypeInfo(TCountrySet). However that would mean having the functions work out what elements are in the set and I simply haven't had the time or inclination to do that yet.

Answer (score 2):

Soap should be used in a platform and language agnostic way - I would design all data transfer objects (DTO) based on simple types e.g. `array of string`, without language specific features. Then map the DTO to the matching business objects. This also will give you an 'anticorruption layer'.